# Simple probability question dealing with Baye's Theorem

Tags: probability

[image: Question]

For part (a)
To calculate this probability I need to know the sample space of the programmers right? This is the main thing I'm having trouble with.

I was thinking I just need to add up how many know Java, C, and Assembly (30 + 25 + 16) for the sample space and divide that by the number of people that know Java. 
The amount of people that know Java would be 30 (Java) + 15 (Java and C) + 6 (Java and Assembly) + 5 (Java and C and Assembly).

So would the probability be 56/107? I'm really not sure about it though because I feel like I'm double-counting somewhere

Comment: Are you familiar with the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion.

Comment: The procedure is wrong. Draw a Venn diagram.

Comment: I expect that the intention of the problem is not that there are 30 people who know java and no other language, but rather, there are 30 people total who know java (and potentially other languages too), among which 15 of them know java and C.  Those 15 who know java and C were already included in the 30 who know java.

Comment: Ah okay so I was double counting after all. So if draw a Venn Diagram initially, would I only have values for the intersections? For example, the intersection for Java and C would be 15, Assembly and C: 10, Java and Assembly: 6, Java and Assembly and C: 5. But I can't put 30 for Java alone, 16 for Assembly alone, and 25 for C alone?

Comment: To build the Venn diagram and having amounts in each disjoint region, build it from the inside-out.  You know the region in the center has 2 elements, then for the 15 people who now Java and C, as 2 are already accounted for in your Venn Diagram, there are 13 remaining who know Java and C but *not* ASM.  Do similarly for the other regions.

Comment: @JMoravitz Hm I think I'm starting to understand, but isn't there 5 for the region in the center?

Answer (score 0):

Use the principle of inclusion and exclusion to count the total number of programmers (assuming all programmers hired by Aggdroid are proficient in at least one of those three languages).

$$\Bbb P(J) = \frac{\vert J\vert}{\vert J\vert + \vert C\vert + \vert A\vert - \vert J\cap A\vert - \vert J\cap C\vert -\vert C\cap A\vert + \vert J\cap C\cap A\vert }$$

Comment: Thank you for this, I was not aware of this formula. To use it though I would need to know how many programmers know exclusively one of each language though right?